# retrieve assets from an entries

Tags: templating, entries, forloop

Im looking up the last 2 entries like this

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('report').limit(2) %}
```

My entry got an assets field called 'portfolio'. I would like to retrieve 8 images in random order. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
  {% for image in entry.portfolio.orderBy('RAND()').limit(8)
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```